# Is a locally compact hereditarily Lindelof Hausdorff space first countable?

Tags: general-topology, first-countable, lindelof-spaces

Is a locally compact hereditarily Lindelof Hausdorff space first countable?

I was recently told that it is but I can't find any reference to what I would have thought would be a standard fact if it is correct.

Comment: Yes, essentially because a $G_\delta$ point in a compact Hausdorff  space has a countable local base.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma. So it would seem that in a locally compact $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space, the properties of being a $G_{\delta}$ point, of having a countable local base, and being a zero-set coincide?

Comment: Why switch to $\sigma$-compact spaces? A locally compact hereditarily Lindelöf space is $\sigma$-compact but a locally compact $\sigma$-compact space need not be hereditarily Lindelöf. You’re switching to a wider class.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma. I was dropping the "hereditarily Lindelof" hypothesis for that statement. I put the $\sigma$-compact in because I feel more confident about zero sets in that context, but perhaps the three properties mentioned are equivalent in general locally compact Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: Yes, in locally compact Hausdorff spaces it's equivalent that 1. $\{x\}$ is a $G_\delta$ 2. $x$ has a countable local base 3. $\{x\}$ is a zero-set. Most of these are standard implications. Local compactness is used to derive 2 from 1 or 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ be a locally compact hereditarily Lindelöf Hausdorff space and let $x\in X$.  Then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is covered by sets of the form $X\setminus K$ where $K$ is a compact neighborhood of $x$.  Since $X\setminus\{x\}$ is Lindelöf, it is in fact covered by countably many such sets $X\setminus K_n$, and we may assume the $K_n$ are nested.  Thus we have a nested sequence of compact neighborhoods $K_n$ of $x$ such that $\bigcap K_n=\{x\}$.  I claim that these are in fact a neighborhood base at $x$.

To prove this, suppose $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ that does not contain any $K_n$.  Pick a point $x_n\in K_n\setminus U$ for each $n$.  Then $x_n\in K_0$ for all $n$, so by compactness the sequence $(x_n)$ accumulates somewhere in $K_0$.  However, since the sequence is eventually in each $K_n$, any accumulation point must be in each $K_n$.  Since $\bigcap K_n=\{x\}$, this means the accumulation point can only be $x$.  But then since $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, infinitely many of the $x_n$ must be in $U$.  This is a contradiction, since $x_n\not\in U$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 4):

It’s true. Since first countability is a local property, it suffices to show that a compact hereditarily Lindelöf Hausdorff space is first countable. If $X$ is a Hausdorff space, $\psi(X)\le hL(X)$, where $\psi(X)$ is the [pseudocharacter](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Pseudo-character_of_a_set) of $X$ and $hL(X)$ is the hereditary Lindelöf degree of $X$. If $X$ is hereditarily Lindelöf, then $hL(X)=\omega$, so $\psi(X)=\omega$. And if $X$ is compact and Hausdorff, then $\psi(X)=\chi(X)$, the character of $X$, so in this setting we get $\chi(X)=\omega$, i.e., $X$ is first countable. Both of these results are noted without proof in R. Hodel, *Cardinal Function I*, in *The Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*, K. Kunen and J.E. Vaughan, eds.: **Theorem** $\bf{(3.8)}$$(f)$, and **Theorem** $\bf{7.1}$. There’s a proof of the former in I. Juhász, *Cardinal Functions in Topology*, Mathematical Centre Tracts 34, **Theorem** $\bf2.17$.

Comment: Thanks for this further helpful information.

Comment: @user558840: You’re welcome.